# Python selenium click on element by xpath not working

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some informations from we webpage like title, locations, contact number.
I used Selenium & BS4 library in python. The webpage only shows the contact number once we click on "Show number" element in the webpage.
I tried to click using selenium but its not working.

**My code (What i'm tried) :**

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
#chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") # linux only
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
# chrome_options.headless = True # also works

#options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # maybe needed if running on Windows.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/dobuyme/Desktop/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
print("Loading Page...")
driver.get('https://smartarz.com/furniture/1114/furniture/3304/beds-bed-sets/3315/6443')
time.sleep(5)
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/app-main/div/ng-component/app-sale-property-detail-page/div/main/div[2]/div[1]/div/app-post-detail-image-gallery/app-gallery/div/app-gallery-thumbnails/div/div")
element.click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
title = soup.find("span", {"class": ["_truncate_multilines multiline_truncation"]}).get_text()
app = soup.find("div", {"class": ["_top_row-destop text-left"]}).find("h2").get_text().strip()
driver.quit()
contact = soup.find("div", {"class": ["_user_contact"]}).find("p", {"class": ["_call text-left"]}).get_text()
print(contact)
```

**Error i'm getting :**

```
Loading Page...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dobuyme/Downloads/BS4 Scrapper/Haraj.com/smart.py", line 18, in <module>
    element.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

I don't know where is wrong with my code. Anyone can sort out the issue and help me to get the contact number printed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath` method returns a list of web elements.
If you want to get a single web element and click it you should use `driver.find_element_by_xpath` method instead.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/app-main/div/ng-component/app-sale-property-detail-page/div/main/div[2]/div[1]/div/app-post-detail-image-gallery/app-gallery/div/app-gallery-thumbnails/div/div")
element.click()
```

Also, you locator is bad. Use this instead:

```
show_number_btn_xpath = '//span[contains(text(),'Show number')]'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(show_number_btn_xpath).click()
```

**UPD**
Since it works correct now in regular mode and throws `element not interactable` error in headless mode I guess you should add

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
```

so if will be

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
```

Comment: This works without selenium headless mode. If i;m trying with headless mode enabled it shows error "Message: element not interactable"

Comment: I guess I have an idea. Please see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/app-main/div/ng-component/app-sale-property-detail-page/div/main/div[2]/div[1]/div/app-post-detail-image-gallery/app-gallery/div/app-gallery-thumbnails/div/div")
```

This will return a list of elements. You probably want the first one:

```
element[0].click()
```